# Drupal 7 and Open ID

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

How does this Open ID module work in Drupal 7? I would expect something more or less the way StackOverflow and all these StackExchange websites work: you pick up your logging provider, like Google or Facebook, by clicking one of them. If you aren't currently logged in in their service, you are redirected to their logging interface, fulfill username and password and you are redirected back to the parent website and already recognized. It looks like the OpenID module does not work this way. You have to paste an Open ID URL or something... Is there a module that does the process exactlys as in the Stack Exchange websites, or more or less the same? Because I think the process implemented in this website is absolutely fantastic: quick and comprehensive, Dummies proof. Or I am afraid I am behaving like the Dummy myself if the Drupal Open ID module works this way. I have been experimenting with it in my localhost and it requires me to paste an OpenId URL. Thanks for any help clearing this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, OpenID always works with an URL, which is your identifier.

I think what you are looking for is the Janrain Engage module: http://drupal.org/project/rpx. This provides a similar workflow and UI like the one you know from StackOverflow.

Comment: Great! It works!

Answer (score 3):

The [OpenID Selector](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_selector) module is another option for creating something similar to the StackExchange **login** process. Unfortunately, it doesn't yet support registration via OpenID, the way StackExchange does.

Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> This module integrates [Javascript OpenID Selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) with Drupal's OpenID client.
>
> This module substitutes Drupal's default OpenID form with Javascript OpenID Selector widget, so users do not even need to know what OpenID URL is.
>
> Javascript OpenID Selector widget is very widely used. For example, it is in use at [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/account/login.php) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login).