# How can I implement OAuth based login, just like drupal.stackexchange.com offers?

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between the various OpenID widgets available?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5724/what-are-the-differences-between-the-various-openid-widgets-available)

I know there is the [Janrain Engage](http://drupal.org/project/rpx) module, but I don't want to depend on an external provider. Can I implement it with any Drupal module?

Comment: Related question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5724/what-are-the-differences-between-the-various-openid-widgets-available

Comment: loginradius.com is an alternative to Janrain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange uses OpenID for single-sign-on, which is not the same as OAuth.  The good news is, OpenID is built-in to Drupal core.  The downside of using the core module is your visitors must know the URL of their OpenID provider.  Most people already have at least one OpenID provider, but [don't know it](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/).

To solve this problem, you could try [OpenID selector](http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector), which offers a login selector similar to SE.

Comment: Nevermind, openid selector fixes it for me since it DOES support OAuth as well (at least for FB and Twitter), although i will have to port it to D7.